# Null on getting map value

Tags: apex, controller, map

I have a code to in controller and I am trying to get the value from the map. Here is the code

```
public Map<String, Integer> daysOfTheWeekMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
daysOfTheWeekMap=assignDaysOfWeekMap();
if (daysOfTheWeekMap.get(dayOfWeek) - daysOfTheWeekMap.get(recurringTaskLPP.daysOfWeek[i]) <= 0) {
                days.add(startDate);
                startDate = startDate + (this.daysOfTheWeekMap.get(dayOfWeek) - this.daysOfTheWeekMap.get(recurringTaskLPP.daysOfWeek[i]));
            }
 public Map<String, Integer> assignDaysOfWeekMap() {
        Map<String,Integer> weekMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
        this.daysOfTheWeekMap.put('Sunday',0);
        this.daysOfTheWeekMap.put('Monday',1);
        this.daysOfTheWeekMap.put('Tuesday',2);
        this.daysOfTheWeekMap.put('Wednesday',3);
        this.daysOfTheWeekMap.put('Thursday',4);
        this.daysOfTheWeekMap.put('Friday',5);
        this.daysOfTheWeekMap.put('Saturday',6);
        return weekMap;
    }
```

Whenever i try and run I get the error in the If statement that I am trying to dereference the null object. The problem is that when dayOfWeek is passed in the map to get the value the map is returning null. When I log dayOfWeek it shows the correct value which means that the problem is in the get from the map. Can anyone solve and tell me why is it giving a null pointer exception in get from the map?? Thanks

Comment: Whats in recurringTaskLPP?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the `.get()` method is at fault. More likely is that your `recurringTaskLPP.daysOfWeek[i]` is returning a value not in your map's keyset. Have you tried system.debug on that part of your expression?

Comment: Yes I tried to do the system .debug actually [i] has an array of string from the other class which also only has weekdays so it is not an issue. The problem is that get method is not returning the correct value. I am passing the key correctly that I checked in the logs

Comment: @Abhinav Pandey, please refer my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a note that you can get the `Day Of Week` value by using `Datetime.format('u')`. It's not in the `SimpleDateFormat` [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), but it works. It's probably missing because it was added in Java 7 and they're outdated. Anyway, try running this snippet in `Execute Anonymous`:

```
static Integer getDayOfWeek(Datetime input)
{
    return Math.mod(Integer.valueOf(input.format('u')), 7);
}
static void debugFormat(Datetime input)
{
    system.debug(input.format('EEEE') + ' - ' + getDayOfWeek(input));
}

Datetime sunday = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(
    Date.newInstance(2016, 6, 26), Time.newInstance(12, 0, 0, 0)
);
debugFormat(sunday);
debugFormat(sunday.addDays(1));
debugFormat(sunday.addDays(2));
debugFormat(sunday.addDays(3));
debugFormat(sunday.addDays(4));
debugFormat(sunday.addDays(5));
debugFormat(sunday.addDays(6));
```

Output:

> Sunday - 0
>   Monday - 1
>   Tuesday - 2
>   Wednesday - 3
>   Thursday - 4
>   Friday - 5
>   Saturday - 6

Comment: Can you also tell me a good way to implement the recurring task functionality in salesforce for the Weekly option?

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a different question. Might be worth asking a new one.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128977/recurring-task-for-weekly-option

Answer (score 1):

In this method `assignDaysOfWeekMap()` replace `daysOfTheWeekMap` with `weekMap` as you are returning `weekMap` from this method which is empty. Updated method will be as follows:

```
public Map<String, Integer> assignDaysOfWeekMap() {
    Map<String,Integer> weekMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
    weekMap.put('Sunday',0);
    weekMap.put('Monday',1);
    weekMap.put('Tuesday',2);
    weekMap.put('Wednesday',3);
    weekMap.put('Thursday',4);
    weekMap.put('Friday',5);
    weekMap.put('Saturday',6);
    return weekMap;
}
```